# Little program - how can I make this code work with a string instead of character?

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

I'm slowly trying to write a program that will convert a hexadecimal number to a decimal. I'm not interested in reading finished, well known codes because I want do it myself. I have an idea but there is something interfering me.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String any = input.nextLine();
        char[] cArray = any.toCharArray();
        for(int i=0; i<cArray.length; i++){
            System.out.print(cArray[i]+" ");
        }
    }
}

Input: ab12
Output: a b 1 2
```

I want replace `a` with `10`, `b` with `11`, `c` with `12`, etc.

It works if I add an if-statement inside the for-loop.

```
        for(int i=0; i<cArray.length; i++){
            if(cArray[i] == 'a'){
               cArray[i] = '10'; // doesn't work, read below
            }
            System.out.print(cArray[i]+" ");
        }
```

The problem is I want replace `a` with `10` and `10` isn't a character anymore since it's made up of two letters. That's why I'd like to know how to make this code work with `strings` instead of `characters`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**

```
'a' - 87 = 10
```

So you can use:

```
(int) cArray[i] - 87
```

Because :

```
(int)'a' = 97
```

Hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of replacing the values in `cArray`, I'd create a StringBuilder, and append all the values to that (since presumably you only want to print out the result):-

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

for(int i=0; i<cArray.length; i++){
        if(cArray[i] == 'a'){
           str.append(10);
        } else if (cArray[i] == 'b'){
           [etc]
        } else {
           str.append(cArray[i]);
        }
}

System.out.print(str.toString());
```

Comment: Simple and effective Steve.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you would want to access the converted decimal digits after extracting them. Use List of String to store your output

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String any = in.nextLine();
    char[] cArray = any.toCharArray();
    List<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0; i<cArray.length; i++){
        if(cArray[i] >= 'a'){ // Strore a,b,c,d,e
            output.add(String.valueOf(10+(cArray[i]-'a'))); 
         } else { // Store numbers
             output.add(String.valueOf(cArray[i])); 
         }
    }
    for(String s : output){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at this:

```
  if (cArray[i] == 'a') {
      cArray[i] = '10'; 
  }
```

This is not valid Java for a couple of reasons:

1. `'10'` is not a valid literal.  It isn't a character literal because there are two characters ... and a character literal can only represent a single character.  It isn't a String literal either, because a String literal is enclosed with double-quote characters; e.g. `"10"`.
2. Assuming we change `'10'` to `"10"` ... it is still wrong.  Now the problem is that `cArray[i] = "10";` is assigning a String object into an array of characters.

The next problem is that you can't "insert" into an array.  Arrays have fixed sizes.  The size of an array cannot change (unless you make a new array).  All you can do is update the character at a given position.

But that doesn't work here either.  You could try to move the characters to the right to make space for the extra characters.  However, then you wouldn't have enough space in the array to hold all of the characters.

In short, you need to represent the modified / rewritten characters as a *new* data structure.  The `StringBuilder` class is the most suitable.  See @SteveSmith's answer for a solution using `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 1):

To make your code work with a string instead of character change the char array to string array:

```
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String any = input.nextLine();
        //char[] cArray = any.toCharArray(); // first change this line
        String [] cArray = any.split("");    // split input into single characters as string
        for(int i=0; i<cArray.length; i++){
            System.out.print(cArray[i]+" ");
        }

        for(int i=0; i<cArray.length; i++){
            if(cArray[i].equals("a")){         // use String.equals("anotherString") method to check equality
               cArray[i] = "10"; 
            }
            System.out.print(cArray[i]+" ");
        }
```